# Event listener, with radio-button stops working

Tags: javascript, events, radio-button, addeventlistener

So I'm making this basic assignment from university, regarding DOM Manipulation.

Basically, I have user profiles on a HTML page, and there are 2 radio boxes - Unlock and Lock. So when you toggle the 'Unlock' and click on a button 'Show More' it shows you the data for that profile, and changes the name of the button to 'Hide it'. Problem is I click on 'Show More', then click on 'Hide it' and then when I click on 'Show more' again it does not work. It's like the whole event listener stops working.

```
function lockedProfile() {
    const $buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

    Array.from($buttons).forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const parent = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
            const checkBox = parent.children[4];

            if (checkBox.checked) {
                parent.children[9].style.display = 'block';
                parent.children[10].textContent = 'Hide it';
                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    if (checkBox.checked) {
                        parent.children[10].textContent = 'Show More';
                        parent.children[9].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I don't know how relevant the HTML Code is, but here it is, if you want to check it:

https://pastebin.com/hDaiKTTZ

Thanks!

Comment: I thing adding a addEventListener inside a addEventListener is a very bad idea, and and the worst way to code

Comment: and you don't need  any eventListener to do that....

Answer (score 0):

the way to folow

```js
const allForms = document.querySelectorAll('form.profile')
  ;
allForms.forEach(f=>
  {
  f.onsubmit=e=>e.preventDefault()  // disable forms submit
    ;
  f.oninput=e=>
    {
    if (e.target.name === 'userLocked')
      {
      f.theButton.textContent = ( f.userLocked.value==='lock' ) ? 'Show More' : 'Hide it'
      }
    }
  })
```

```css
.profile {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e29fc1;
  margin: 2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<form class="profile">
  my radio  button 1
  <p>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="userLocked" value="lock" checked> Lock </label>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="userLocked" value="unlock"      >  Unlock </label>
  </p>
  <button name="theButton">Show more</button>
</form>

<form class="profile">
  my radio  button 2
  <p>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="userLocked" value="lock" checked> Lock </label>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="userLocked" value="unlock"      >  Unlock </label>
  </p>
  <button name="theButton">Show more</button>
</form>

<form class="profile">
  my radio  button 3
  <p>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="userLocked" value="lock" checked> Lock </label>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="userLocked" value="unlock"      >  Unlock </label>
  </p>
  <button name="theButton">Show more</button>
</form>
```